# Azure AD B2C: Sign in with apple "Sign-up not completed"

Tags: ios, azure, azure-ad-b2c, apple-sign-in, appauth

We are integrating Azure AD B2C with User Flows. We have followed the [guid found here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-apple-id?pivots=b2c-user-flow) for implementation.

On iOS side we are using [AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS). Once we launch OIDAuthState

1. We get a page authentication options i.e Facebook, Gmail, Apple and PhoneNumber.
2. We choose Apple.
3. iOS present Apple Sign In controller. **Our app logo does not appear here.**
4. We authorised it with finger print.
5. Loader shows for 2-3 seconds with message "Signing in"
6. Then we get **"Sign-Up not completed"**

This is working perfectly fine on Safari (iOS 14.5 & macOS Big Sur) with same steps.

We found a troubleshooting [guide at this link](https://fluffy.es/how-to-solve-invalid_client-error-in-sign-in-with-apple/). According to this link our client_id should be bundle identifier of app instead of service id. Once we updated it.

1. **Our apps logo appears** on presented Apple Sign In controller
2. We have same result i.e "Sig-up not completed". on iOS
3. This also stoped working on Safari (macOS Big Sur) which was previously working.

**EDIT:**

Adding image for failure message on Apple Sign In Controller

[image]

[image]

Comment: Azure AD B2C says "Sign Up not completed"? Its not clear which service throws the error.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT, It's failing on Apple Sign In Controller. I have added an image to question

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution to this in the end?